# Function Proxy .toString() Errors

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tostring, es6-proxy

I am trying to call .toString() on a function proxy.

Simply creating a function proxy and calling toString causes "TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic", setting the toString to return the source of the original causes "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded", but creating a get trap for toString works.

Why does simply setting the toString function not work, but making a get trap does?

```js
function wrap(source) {
 return(new Proxy(source, {}))
}
wrap(function() { }).toString()
```

```js
function wrap(source) {
 let proxy = new Proxy(source, {})
 proxy.toString = function() {
  return(source.toString())
 }
 return(proxy)
}
wrap(function() { }).toString()
```

```js
function wrap(source) {
 return(new Proxy(source, {
  get(target, key) {
   if(key == "toString") {
    return(function() {
     return(source.toString())
    })
   } else {
    return(Reflect.get(source, key))
} } })) }
wrap(function() { }).toString()
```

Comment: related: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/calling-tostring-on-function-proxy-throws-typeerror-exception

Comment: Unrelated: `return` is a keyword, not a function in itself, so it's `return x` not `return(x)`. The parens doesn't do anything here.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue. I finally figured out that it's an issue with `this`. Add a `get` trap to your handler, bind the proxied object as `this` on the proxied property if it's a `function`, and it seems to work okay:

```js
function wrap(source) {
    return new Proxy(source, {
        get: function (target, name) {
            const property = target[name];
            return (typeof property === 'function') 
                ? property.bind(target)
                : property;
        }
    });
}

console.log(wrap(function () {}).toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

> TypeError: Function.prototype.toString is not generic

Seems like `Function.prototype.toString` is not supposed to be called on `Proxy`.

> ```
> proxy.toString = function() {
> ```

This assignment to proxy is passed to the `source` object as you do not have trap for assignment. If you check `source.hasOwnProperty('toString')` you'll get `true`. When you add `get` trap, you don't change `toString` method and don't add it into `source` object, so it works.

The other possible solution is

```
function wrap(source) {
  let proxy = new Proxy(source, {})
  proxy.toString = Function.prototype.toString.bind(source)
  return proxy
}
```