# How to set an object property with type checking, but trigger a function on change

Tags: typescript

I've a class looking like this:

```
export class Settings {
 public controls: SettingControls {
    toolbarOpen: false,
    awaitingHttpResponse: false,
    selectedTab: TabOption.NOTIFICATIONS,
    selectedTheme: ThemeOption.DARK
    // etc. (the actual amount of controls is much longer)
  };
}
```

I want to detect when a change is made to the `controls` property and announce it with an observable. Currently I do it with a simple `setControl` function (and set the `_controls` property to private):

```
setControl(key, value) {
  this._controls[key] = value;
  this._updatedSetting.next({key, value}); // Announce the change
}
```

This works, but it means the value's type isn't being checked. I've looked at dynamically generating a getter and setter ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45239384/2810775)), but that doesn't help unfortunately. I could write out a getter/setting for each property individually, but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by installing accessors (getters/setters) as you already said. Type checking by typescript will get performed when you are trying to assign a value to a property of the controls object (that has the type SettingsControl). Take a look at the following code, it calls fireControlUpdated when a value is assigned to any property of the controls object and does type checking.

Note that you should call installAccessors() each time you add/remove a property of the controls object for this to work.

```
enum ENUM1 {
    val1,
    val2,
}

enum ENUM2 {
    val1,
    val2,
}

interface SettingsControls {
    toolbarOpen: boolean,
        awaitingHttpResponse: boolean,
        selectedTab: ENUM1,
        selectedTheme: ENUM2
}

class Settings {
    private _controls = {};
    public controls: SettingsControls = {
        toolbarOpen: false,
        awaitingHttpResponse: false,
        selectedTab: ENUM1.val2,
        selectedTheme: ENUM2.val1
    };

    constructor() {
        this.installAccessors();
    }

    installAccessors() {
        for (let key in this.controls) {
            if (this.controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                Object.defineProperty(this.controls, key, {
                    get: () => { return this._controls[key]; },
                    set: (v: any) => {
                        console.log(this);
                        this._controls[key] = v;
                        this.fireControlUpdated(key, v);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    fireControlUpdated(key: string, v: any) {
      console.log(`key ${key}: new value: ${v}`)
    }
}

let a = new Settings();

a.controls.toolbarOpen = true;

// the following will produce typescript compile error because 
// the type of the selectedTab is ENUM1

// a.controls.selectedTab = ENUM2.val1;

// this one works
a.controls.selectedTab = ENUM1.val2;

console.log("toolbarOpen is: " + a.controls.toolbarOpen);
console.log("selectedTab is: " + ENUM1[a.controls.selectedTab]);
```